# Module not found: Package path ./generated is not exported from package Contentlayer nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentlayer

[image]  I get this error that Module "contentlayer/generated" and its corresponding type declarations are not found.

Solution please .I have installed and updated the dependencies,if someone had the same problem and how the solution

Answer (score 2):

https://www.contentlayer.dev/docs/getting-started-cddd76b7#3-add-site-code

> Notice that you'll get an error when trying to import from contentlayer/generated, it's normal but we're going to fix it later by running the development server.

as the name indicating, it's generated. you need to run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` to make `contentlayer` generating files in the `.contentlayer/generated folder`.

Answer (score 1):

In package.json, I updated scripts to:
"dev": "contentlayer dev & next dev",

You can read more in depth about this issue here:
https://github.com/contentlayerdev/contentlayer/issues/415